# SegmentedControlIOS forceUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I react-native's SegmentedControlIOS component for choosing between three values which works fine so far. However, when my application is loading data I want to ensure that the user can not change the value associated with that control as this would cause concurrency issues and interrupts the update.

Thus I decided that the method for handling the control's value change only calls the callback supplied via a property if the loading process is currently not active. Otherwise, I call `this.forceUpdate()` in order to rerender the host component which includes setting the `selectedIndex` property of the segmented control. However, when `this.forceUpdate` is invoked the selected index does not change. Therefore, I decided to print the value `selectedIndex`is set to which always displays the initial (wished) index.

Below you can see the code of my `rendering` method for displaying the segmented control:

```
render: function()
{
    ...
    var indexBluetoothAutostart = 0;
    switch (this.props.data.BluetoothAutostartState)
    {
        case BluetoothAutostartState.OFF:
            indexBluetoothAutostart = 1;
            break;
        case BluetoothAutostartState.ON:
            indexBluetoothAutostart = 2;
            break;
        case BluetoothAutostartState.AUTO:
            indexBluetoothAutostart = 0;
            break;
    }
    console.log("index: " + indexBluetoothAutostart);
    ...
    return (
        ...
        <SegmentedControlIOS selectedIndex={indexBluetoothAutostart}
            momentary={false}
            onValueChange={(newValue) => this.changeBluetoothAutostartState(newValue)}
            values={[Localization.HomeFragment.BluetoothAutostartState.btnAuto, Localization.HomeFragment.BluetoothAutostartState.btnOff, Localization.HomeFragment.BluetoothAutostartState.btnOn]}/>
    );
}
```

Finally, the following snippet shows the `onValueChange` handler:

```
changeBluetoothAutostartState: function(newValue)
{
    if (newValue === Localization.HomeFragment.BluetoothAutostartState.btnAuto)
    {
        if (this.props.bluetoothConnectionBusy === true)
        {
            Toast.display(Localization.BluetoothOperationInProgress.msgWaitForUploadToFinishToast);
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
        else
        {
            this.props.onBluetoothAutostartStateChange(BluetoothAutostartState.AUTO);
        }
    }
    // process the other two options
    ...
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added a timestamp variable initialized with 'Date.now()' to the class' state and instead of invoking 'this.forceUpdate' I updated the state's timestamp:

```
this.setState({ timestamp: Date.now() });
```